# HP-Proliant DL380 G6

Tags: windows, hp-proliant, partition

Was able to get a Windows 10 based Operating System functioning on the server, sadly the other motherboard broke from other unrelated issues, replaced the motherboard, and cannot remember which setting partitions the drive sections to actually work and allow the Windows 10 based OS to install, it worked fine on the previous motherboard, but there was a setting I adjusted, though I cannot for the life of me remember what setting it was.

The OS Won't install due to the drives being GPT Partitioned.
I am using a Standard Windows 10 64BIT installer Disk, the same disk that worked fine on the previous Motherboard.
In other cases it just gives me a black screen saying Attempting to Boot from C:, and in other cases it gives me a red screen saying "illegal Opcode" And some error codes, I will keep trying, but extra help would be appricated.

Hopefully someone can help me I really gotta get this machine back up and running, these clients won't wait long.

Server Specifications:

````
CPUs: x2 Intel Xeon X5670 2.93GHz 6 Cores 12 Threads at 32nm Technology (Total of 12 cores and 24 Threads)
Motherboard: HP ProLiant DL380 G6 Intel® 5520
RAM: Currently 4GB per CPU (Will increase later)
PSU: Dual 750W (Total Draw of 1500W)
HDD#1: 146GB
HDD#2: 146GB
HDD#3: Blank
HDD#4: Blank
HDD#5: 146GB
HDD#6: 146GB
HDD#7: 146GB
HDD#8: 146GB
GPU: Nvidia Quardo K2000```
````

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest first updating the firmware to the latest version.

Secondly, it sounds like you may have created and booted mbr Windows 10 install disk, can you ensure that you have created an uefi/gpt version?

Comment: I'm not too sure, My main skill is hardware, when it comes to Software I'm essentially clueless, would you be able to provide more specific instructions, By the way I am using WIndows 10 Installer Disk to install a workstation OS, since this server is repurposed to a Workstation. 

Otherwise I am thinking a PCI-E NVM SSD might allow the OS to install.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is too little information provided to be able to help much further. However, this youtube video may help: You will likely need to load the storage array driver for Windows 10: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qMXiHfv1NTY